# Nginx replace PEM files in configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm configuring my Nginx with some provided certificates.

At first, I tried with self signed certificates, and it works.
I just used:

```
$ sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt

$ sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 2048
```

And editing my self certificates file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
```

And including the pem file:

```
$ /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Generating a bak file

```
$ sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.bak
```

And editing the file: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

With

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    ....
}
```

To test if all is ok, I execute:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Ok, that is working, and display a message:

> This connection is not secure

And that is OK, because is a self-signed certificate.

But, at the moment to replace with the valid pem files, my provider sent me 2 files:

`yourdomain.app-key.pem` and `yourdomain.app-cert.pem`

I puth them in the right place and update the file with:

$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/yourdomain.app-cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/yourdomain.app-key.pem;
```

To test if all is ok, I execute:

```
sudo nginx -t

sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But, when I try to visit the site, still appears my own self-signed certificate.

What step am I losing in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `sudo nginx -t` you're just testing the configuration **not** applying it. Try to reload the nginx service (the actual command depends on your OS)

```
$ sudo service nginx reload
```

or

```
$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Then revisit the site, if it still fails, try using private browser mode to verify that it's not some sort of browser caching issue

Comment: I just reload nginx but, in a private window I get: `Your connection is not private` (just the same error) @Misantorp

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried using `curl`? What is the ouput of `curl -vk 'https://you.hostname.com'`

Comment: There looks ok, display the nginx default page there, but in the browser (in any mode, cleaning the cache, etc. still no)

Comment: The `-k` parameter actually ignores invalid certificates, you should read the output before the actual HTML content carefully or try to remove that parameter - ie `curl -v 'https://you.hostname.com'` and see what happens